# Extract common styles with ExtractTextPlugin and CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: css, webpack-2, extract-text-plugin, commonschunkplugin, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm trying to extract common chunk from my `css` according [wiki section](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/stylesheets#styles-in-commons-chunk). I know that this docs is for `webpack 1` but for `webpack 2` [seems like there is no corresponding example yet](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#commonschunkplugin). I use the following webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: srcPath,
    entry: {
        foo: './css/pages/foo.css',
        bar: './css/pages/bar.css'
    },
    output: {
        path: distPath,
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
                'css-loader'
            ])
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'common',
            minChunks: 2
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].[contenthash:base64:5].css',
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

I can't get why `common.css` is not appears after building. Just `common.js`, `foo.js`, `bar.js`, `foo.css` and `bar.css`. Am I missing something? I'm new in webpack.

Thanks.

Comment: seems odd to me - entry point are css files ? for me to help, i need clarity on this

Comment: @VISHALDAGA Actually I have js files as entries too, I just simplified example.

Answer (score 1):

Reference https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#options

`minChunks` means module which need to be contained at least two times will bundle into `common.css`.

Now, no detail about entry `foo.css` and `bar.css`, but you can check it first. :)